# How to run the same tests with different configuration in jest?

Tags: jestjs

I have a test suite and because it contains some expensive tests, I disable some of them for our CI. However once a day, I'd like to run the whole test suite.

The issue is that running against the same set of test files, it causes snapshot failures because when running the whole test suite it is missing some. If I generate them, then the CI fails because it complains about snapshots being removed (i.e. the one from the whole test suite that are not being checked on the CI.)

What would be the proper way to handle this with jest?

Thanks!